# Symbol for coboundary operator $\delta$ or $d$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, homology-cohomology

Hatcher (Chapter 3) and Munkres both use $\delta$ for coboundary operator.

Other sources seems to use $d$.

I am curious is there a convention that for **simplicial** coboundary operator, $\delta$ is used? Or are both symbols equally popular?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, $\delta$ is typically used for the coboundary map in simplicial cohomology, but this is not universal, and $d$ is sometimes used instead.  So I wouldn't say there is any solid convention; it is perhaps traditional to use $\delta$, but no one will yell at you for using the wrong notation if you use $d$.

In more general contexts, both $d$ and $\delta$ are quite common for coboundary maps.  The only contexts I can think of where there is a really solid convention to use one rather than the other is in de Rham cohomology and in spectral sequences, where $d$ is always used rather than $\delta$.